# parse.com not working in android 2.3

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-2.3-gingerbread

I'm using Parse api for my app and notice an issue that this api not working as experted.
Here are my code:

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if(list!=null)
            {
                //...
            }
        }
    });
```

This work good on android 4.0 but on **android 2.3** this return **ParseException**:

```
com.parse.ParseRequest$ParseRequestException: i/o failure
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest.newTemporaryException(ParseRequest.java:372)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:198)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$2.then(ParseRequest.java:190)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jan 06 01:08:18 GMT+00:00 1980, validation time: Tue Oct 22 12:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013
01-06 01:08:18.965    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:477)
01-06 01:08:18.975    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
01-06 01:08:18.975    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.verifyHostname(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:199)
01-06 01:08:18.975    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at android.net.SSLCertificateSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLCertificateSocketFactory.java:259)
01-06 01:08:18.985    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLSocketFactory.createSocket(SSLSocketFactory.java:375)
01-06 01:08:18.985    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:164)
01-06 01:08:18.985    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
01-06 01:08:18.985    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:359)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseApacheHttpClient.executeInternal(ParseApacheHttpClient.java:95)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:147)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParsePlugins$1.intercept(ParsePlugins.java:103)
01-06 01:08:18.995    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseHttpClient$ParseNetworkInterceptorChain.proceed(ParseHttpClient.java:136)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseHttpClient.execute(ParseHttpClient.java:111)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:187)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at com.parse.ParseRequest$3.then(ParseRequest.java:184)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$14.run(Task.java:796)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.BoltsExecutors$ImmediateExecutor.execute(BoltsExecutors.java:105)
01-06 01:08:19.005    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.completeAfterTask(Task.java:787)
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:599)
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task.continueWithTask(Task.java:610)
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:702)
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at bolts.Task$12.then(Task.java:690)
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ ... 4 more
01-06 01:08:19.015    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jan 06 01:08:18 GMT+00:00 1980, validation time: Tue Oct 22 12:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013
01-06 01:08:19.025    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:161)
01-06 01:08:19.025    1593-1595/my.package.name D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_CONCURRENT freed 399K, 44% free 3521K/6215K, external 0K/0K, paused 6ms+10ms
01-06 01:08:19.035    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:664)
01-06 01:08:19.035    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
01-06 01:08:19.035    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:474)
01-06 01:08:19.035    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ ... 29 more
01-06 01:08:19.035    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ Caused by: org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate: current time: Sun Jan 06 01:08:18 GMT+00:00 1980, validation time: Tue Oct 22 12:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1521)
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.engineValidate(PKIXCertPathValidatorSpi.java:399)
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at java.security.cert.CertPathValidator.validate(CertPathValidator.java:197)
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:156)
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ ... 32 more
01-06 01:08:19.045    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateNotYetValidException: current time: Sun Jan 06 01:08:18 GMT+00:00 1980, validation time: Tue Oct 22 12:00:00 GMT+00:00 2013
01-06 01:08:19.055    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.apache.harmony.security.provider.cert.X509CertImpl.checkValidity(X509CertImpl.java:178)
01-06 01:08:19.055    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.RFC3280CertPathUtilities.processCertA(RFC3280CertPathUtilities.java:1512)
01-06 01:08:19.055    1593-1593/my.package.name W/System.err﹕ ... 35 more
```

Please help me to fix this. Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

This code have to be work for 2.3 also based on documentation from [parse](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#getting-started)

Might be U have to import bolts-android.x.x.x jar file ....

and 
test  like below code once

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Group");
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
    @Override
    public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
        if(e!=null)
        {
            //...
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("Error",e.getMessage());
            // r use Toast with e.getMessage()
        }
    }
});
```

You will get what's the parse error is ....

Answer (score 0):

try on this way.

```
ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<ParseObject>("Group");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> list, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                // ...
                // Success
                if (list.size() > 0) {
                    // get array list more then zero
                } else {
                    // not geting data
                }
            } else {
                Log.e("Error ...... ", e.getMessage());
                // r use Toast with e.getMessage()
            }
        }
    });
```

check your class name.
or also check parse secret key or client key on main activity.
in else case u got the error so do comment.